# ¿Cómo colocar una ventana dentro de otra ventana empleando PYQT5 con Python?

Tags: python, pyqt5

He estado investigando en varios lugares de StackOsverFlow, pero no logro comprender como mandar a llamar o enlazar las ventanas entre ellas. Estos son algunos lugares de donde he estado revisando.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704265/python-qtdesigner-opening-multiple-py-files-in-mdiarea-window-with-buttons

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515978/how-to-put-widgets-inside-a-pyqt-qmdisubwindow

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470433/how-to-put-a-child-window-inside-a-main-windowpyqt

Más abajo se muestra el código de mi primera ventana que va a ser la MainWindow.py, en la que quiero mandar a llamar las sub-ventanas (subVENTANA1.py y subVENTANA2.py), la cual quiero colocarla dentro del área del mdiArea.
Como se puede observar en la imagen, la ventana principal solo tiene la barra de tareas de donde al dar clic en uno de los menús me despliegan los consecuentes submenús. Para ello, al dar clic en Menu A -> Mostrar subventana 1 me mandaría a llamar la ventana subVENTANA1.py y así con la siguiente.

Venta MainWindows.py

[image: Ventana Principal creada con PyQT5]

Sub ventanas subVENTANA1.py y subVENTANA2.py

[image: Subventanas creadas con PQT5]

Estos son los códigos
Código de MainWindows.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_mainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, mainWindow):
        mainWindow.setObjectName("mainWindow")
        mainWindow.resize(670, 548)
        mainWindow.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(mainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.mdiArea = QtWidgets.QMdiArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.mdiArea.setObjectName("mdiArea")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.mdiArea, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        mainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(mainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 670, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuAn_lisis = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuAn_lisis.setObjectName("menuAn_lisis")
        self.menuEliminar_ruido = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuEliminar_ruido.setObjectName("menuEliminar_ruido")
        self.menuMenu_C = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuMenu_C.setObjectName("menuMenu_C")
        mainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(mainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        mainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionNDVI = QtWidgets.QAction(mainWindow)
        self.actionNDVI.setObjectName("actionNDVI")
        self.actionEliminar_Ruido = QtWidgets.QAction(mainWindow)
        self.actionEliminar_Ruido.setObjectName("actionEliminar_Ruido")
        self.actionBrillo_Contraste = QtWidgets.QAction(mainWindow)
        self.actionBrillo_Contraste.setObjectName("actionBrillo_Contraste")
        self.actionDetecci_n_de_Bordes = QtWidgets.QAction(mainWindow)
        self.actionDetecci_n_de_Bordes.setObjectName("actionDetecci_n_de_Bordes")
        self.actionEcualizaci_n = QtWidgets.QAction(mainWindow)
        self.actionEcualizaci_n.setObjectName("actionEcualizaci_n")
        self.actionMostrar_ventna_4 = QtWidgets.QAction(mainWindow)
        self.actionMostrar_ventna_4.setObjectName("actionMostrar_ventna_4")
        self.actionMostar_subventna2 = QtWidgets.QAction(mainWindow)
        self.actionMostar_subventna2.setObjectName("actionMostar_subventna2")
        self.menuAn_lisis.addAction(self.actionBrillo_Contraste)
        self.menuAn_lisis.addAction(self.actionMostar_subventna2)
        self.menuEliminar_ruido.addAction(self.actionEliminar_Ruido)
        self.menuEliminar_ruido.addAction(self.actionMostrar_ventna_4)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuAn_lisis.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuEliminar_ruido.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuMenu_C.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(mainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(mainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, mainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        mainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("mainWindow", "Venta principal"))
        self.menuAn_lisis.setTitle(_translate("mainWindow", "Memu A"))
        self.menuEliminar_ruido.setTitle(_translate("mainWindow", "Menu B"))
        self.menuMenu_C.setTitle(_translate("mainWindow", "Menu C"))
        self.actionNDVI.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "NDVI"))
        self.actionEliminar_Ruido.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Mostar subventna 3"))
        self.actionBrillo_Contraste.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Mostar subventna 1"))
        self.actionDetecci_n_de_Bordes.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Detección de Bordes"))
        self.actionEcualizaci_n.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Ecualización"))
        self.actionMostrar_ventna_4.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Mostar subventna 4"))
        self.actionMostar_subventna2.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Mostar subventna 2"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_mainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(mainWindow)
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Código de subVENTANA1.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_subWindow1(object):
    def setupUi(self, subWindow1):
        subWindow1.setObjectName("subWindow1")
        subWindow1.resize(388, 300)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        subWindow1.setFont(font)
        subWindow1.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        subWindow1.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(subWindow1)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem2, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        subWindow1.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(subWindow1)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 388, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        subWindow1.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(subWindow1)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        subWindow1.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(subWindow1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(subWindow1)

    def retranslateUi(self, subWindow1):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        subWindow1.setWindowTitle(_translate("subWindow1", "Sub Ventna 1"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("subWindow1", "Imagen original"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("subWindow1", "Abrir imagen"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    subWindow1 = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_subWindow1()
    ui.setupUi(subWindow1)
    subWindow1.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Código de subVENTANA2.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_subWindow2(object):
    def setupUi(self, subWindow2):
        subWindow2.setObjectName("subWindow2")
        subWindow2.resize(366, 299)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        subWindow2.setFont(font)
        subWindow2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        subWindow2.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(subWindow2)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem2, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        subWindow2.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(subWindow2)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 366, 23))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        subWindow2.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(subWindow2)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        subWindow2.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(subWindow2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(subWindow2)

    def retranslateUi(self, subWindow2):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        subWindow2.setWindowTitle(_translate("subWindow2", "Sub Ventana 2"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("subWindow2", "Imagen procesada"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("subWindow2", "Ver"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    subWindow2 = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_subWindow2()
    ui.setupUi(subWindow2)
    subWindow2.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Pista: En una de meter una ventana dentro de otra, convierte tu 2da ventana en un QWidget, y mete ese QWidget dentro de un contenedor de la primera ventana.

Comment: OK, voy a cambiar primero las ventanas a un QWitdget, después averiguo como hacer lo del contenedor, soy novato en esto y apenas voy empezando hacer uso de QT Designer, gracias por la pista Saelyth

Comment: Además de eso, solo deberías tener un __init__ en tu aplicación, y no uno para cada ventana. De lo contrario es como si fueran aplicaciones distintas y no enlazadas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Intentalo:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


#from subVENTANA2 import Ui_subWindow2
class Ui_subWindow2(object):
    def setupUi(self, subWindow2):
        subWindow2.setObjectName("subWindow2")
        subWindow2.resize(366, 299)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        subWindow2.setFont(font)
        subWindow2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        subWindow2.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(subWindow2)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem2, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        subWindow2.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(subWindow2)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 366, 23))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        subWindow2.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(subWindow2)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        subWindow2.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(subWindow2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(subWindow2)

    def retranslateUi(self, subWindow2):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        subWindow2.setWindowTitle(_translate("subWindow2", "Sub Ventana 2"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("subWindow2", "Imagen procesada"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("subWindow2", "Ver"))


#from subVENTANA1 import Ui_subWindow1
class Ui_subWindow1(object):
    def setupUi(self, subWindow1):
        subWindow1.setObjectName("subWindow1")
        subWindow1.resize(388, 300)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        subWindow1.setFont(font)
        subWindow1.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        subWindow1.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(subWindow1)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem2, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        subWindow1.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(subWindow1)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 388, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        subWindow1.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(subWindow1)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        subWindow1.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(subWindow1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(subWindow1)

    def retranslateUi(self, subWindow1):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        subWindow1.setWindowTitle(_translate("subWindow1", "Sub Ventna 1"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("subWindow1", "Imagen original"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("subWindow1", "Abrir imagen"))


#from MainWindows import Ui_mainWindow
class Ui_mainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, mainWindow):
        mainWindow.setObjectName("mainWindow")
        mainWindow.resize(670, 548)
        mainWindow.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(mainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        
        self.mdiArea = QtWidgets.QMdiArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.mdiArea.setObjectName("mdiArea")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.mdiArea, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        
        mainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(mainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 670, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuAn_lisis = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuAn_lisis.setObjectName("menuAn_lisis")
        self.menuEliminar_ruido = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuEliminar_ruido.setObjectName("menuEliminar_ruido")
        self.menuMenu_C = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuMenu_C.setObjectName("menuMenu_C")
        mainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(mainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        mainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionNDVI = QtWidgets.QAction(mainWindow)
        self.actionNDVI.setObjectName("actionNDVI")
        self.actionEliminar_Ruido = QtWidgets.QAction(mainWindow)
        self.actionEliminar_Ruido.setObjectName("actionEliminar_Ruido")
        self.actionBrillo_Contraste = QtWidgets.QAction(mainWindow)
        self.actionBrillo_Contraste.setObjectName("actionBrillo_Contraste")
        self.actionDetecci_n_de_Bordes = QtWidgets.QAction(mainWindow)
        self.actionDetecci_n_de_Bordes.setObjectName("actionDetecci_n_de_Bordes")
        self.actionEcualizaci_n = QtWidgets.QAction(mainWindow)
        self.actionEcualizaci_n.setObjectName("actionEcualizaci_n")
        self.actionMostrar_ventna_4 = QtWidgets.QAction(mainWindow)
        self.actionMostrar_ventna_4.setObjectName("actionMostrar_ventna_4")
        self.actionMostar_subventna2 = QtWidgets.QAction(mainWindow)
        self.actionMostar_subventna2.setObjectName("actionMostar_subventna2")
        self.menuAn_lisis.addAction(self.actionBrillo_Contraste)
        self.menuAn_lisis.addAction(self.actionMostar_subventna2)
        self.menuEliminar_ruido.addAction(self.actionEliminar_Ruido)
        self.menuEliminar_ruido.addAction(self.actionMostrar_ventna_4)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuAn_lisis.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuEliminar_ruido.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuMenu_C.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(mainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(mainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, mainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        mainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("mainWindow", "Venta principal"))
        self.menuAn_lisis.setTitle(_translate("mainWindow", "Memu A"))
        self.menuEliminar_ruido.setTitle(_translate("mainWindow", "Menu B"))
        self.menuMenu_C.setTitle(_translate("mainWindow", "Menu C"))
        self.actionNDVI.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "NDVI"))
        self.actionEliminar_Ruido.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Mostar subventna 3"))
        self.actionBrillo_Contraste.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Mostar subventna 1"))
        self.actionDetecci_n_de_Bordes.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Detección de Bordes"))
        self.actionEcualizaci_n.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Ecualización"))
        self.actionMostrar_ventna_4.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Mostar subventna 4"))
        self.actionMostar_subventna2.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Mostar subventna 2"))


class Window2(QMainWindow, Ui_subWindow2):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window2, self).__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        

class Window1(QMainWindow, Ui_subWindow1):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window1, self).__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)


class Demo(QMainWindow, Ui_mainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Demo, self).__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.actionBrillo_Contraste.triggered.connect(self.new_func1)  
        self.actionMostar_subventna2.triggered.connect(self.new_func2) 
        
    def new_func1(self):
        widget = Window1()
        sub = QMdiSubWindow()
        sub.setWidget(widget)
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(sub)
        sub.show()   
        
    def new_func2(self):
        widget = Window2()
        sub = QMdiSubWindow()
        sub.setWidget(widget)
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(sub)
        sub.show()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = Demo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, eres increíble, con la ayuda de tu ejemplo pude resolver la colocación de mi ventana en `mdiArea` ya solo me faltaba saber como usar estar parte `self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(sub)` y había encontrado la forma de mandar a llamar a la función desde `self.actionBrillo_Contraste.triggered.connect(self.new_func1)`, pero no entendía como conectar el `mdiArea` y lo estaba conectando desde una misma línea todo.

Answer (score 0):

Con la ayuda de S. Nick cree una nueva clase llamada MiddlewareWindow.py en donde lo hice de la siguiente manera:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMenuBar, QMainWindow, QWidget, QPushButton, QAction

from MainWindow import Ui_mainWindow
from subVENTANA1 import Ui_subWindow1
from subVENTANA2 import Ui_subWindow2

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_mainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.actionBrillo_Contraste.triggered.connect(self.abrirVentana1)
        
    def abrirVentana1(self):
        self.ventana = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_subWindow1()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.ventana)
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.ventana)
        self.ventana.show()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Esta fue la solución a la que llegue.